# How to make Listview automatically jump at a position if scrolled?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have this ListView with 100dp padding between elements so that on scroll only one element is shown at a time.

The problem is that whenever I scroll, the respective element on the respective position isn't focused (it is not in the middle of my layout, just like in a Gallery), the scroll may pass further and show only half of it.

I want that OnScroll users to only see the next element at a time and to scroll again if they want to pass to the next one but also those elements to be centered in my listview.

This is very similar to Gallery's OnFling, if you scroll half of the distance between elements, it focuses on the closest one.